# Where is the apk file when using a Custom Test Spec in AWS device farm?

Tags: aws-device-farm, courgette

I've followed this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-test-run.html and i'm running a Custom Test Spec (see step 5). Where is the apk that I uploaded in step 3 on the file system so that my Courgette tests can point to them?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer in the example test spec: $DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH